# Puppet：Could not find default node or by name with node test2

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I installed Puppet 3.1.1 on an Ubuntu Server.

My manifests folder looked like this:

```
├── nodes
│   └── test1.pp
└── site.pp
```

The content of site.pp was:

```
# site.pp
import "nodes/*.pp"
```

Node test1 worked OK.

Then I created a new file named `test2.pp`.  The content was the same as test1.pp except for the node name, and I added it into the nodes folder.

So the manifests folder became this:

```
├── nodes
│   ├── test1.pp
│   └── test2.pp
└── site.pp
```

I then ran `puppet agent --test` on node test2.

The agent could exchange SSL keys with the puppet master, but I got an error message:

```
Could not find default node or by name with test2
```

If I don't create a new `test2.pp` file, and just add the content into the `test1.pp` file, no error appears.

So I am thinking Puppet will not dynamically import a new pp file after the puppet master has been started.

Is is possible to define nodes in individual pp files and dynamically import them?

Glad for any suggestions.

---

The content of the two pp files:

```
node 'test1' {
  include tmp::params
  tmp::gtp { 'node1':
    name            => 'node1',
    version         => '6.0.0.0',
    ip              => '168.1.193.97',
    port            => '1255',
  }
}

node 'test2' {
  include tmp::params
  tmp::gtp { 'node2':
    name            => 'node2',
    version         => '6.0.0.0',
    ip              => '168.1.193.98',
    port            => '1255',
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of the two node files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend moving away from manifest node definitions to Hiera.  You'll need to tweak things a bit to move away from having that defined type called directly from your node, but it looks like that isn't being used multiple times in a catalog anyway, so conversion to a class should work fine.

So with a `hiera.yaml` like this..

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - '%{::clientcert}'
  - 'os-%{::osfamily}'
  - common

:yaml:
   :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
```

And a `site.pp` with just:

```
hiera_include(classes)
```

..your nodes will be read from YAML files in `/etc/puppet/hieradata`.  For example's sake we'll say that you want `tmp::params` on every node reporting to Puppet, but maybe you want `tmp::gtp` just on certain nodes.  And you want to centrally define the `version` parameter, but leave the other parameters to be set per-node.  So we'll put `tmp::params` and the `version` parameter `/etc/puppet/hieradata/common.yaml`:

```
classes:
  - tmp::params

tmp::gtp::version: 6.0.0.0
```

Then you'll have a file for each node.

`/etc/puppet/hieradata/test1.yaml`:

```
classes:
  - tmp::gtp

tmp::gtp::name : node1
tmp::gtp::ip   : 168.1.193.97
tmp::gtp::port : 1255
```

`/etc/puppet/hieradata/test2.yaml`:

```
classes:
  - tmp::gtp

tmp::gtp::name : node2
tmp::gtp::ip   : 168.1.193.98
tmp::gtp::port : 1255
```

And yes, it'll pick up changes to the Hiera files without a service restart.  Seem like about what you need?

**Edit**: to use Hiera to set up multiple instances of a defined type, you'll want to do something like this:

`/etc/puppet/hieradata/test1.yaml`:

```
classes:
  - gtpsetup

gtp_instances:
  - node1_instance1
  - node1_instance2

gtp_instanceconfig:
  node1_instance1:
    ip      : 168.1.193.97
    port    : 1255
    version : 5.3.2.1

  node1_instance2:
    ip      : 168.1.193.97
    port    : 1268
    version : 6.0.0.0
```

`/etc/puppet/modules/gtpsetup/manifests/init.pp`:

```
class gtpsetup {
  gtp_instances = hiera('gtp_instances')
  gtp_instanceconfig = hiera('gtp_instanceconfig')

  define gtp_instance {
    # this is using your existing defined type, but you can just move the stuff it's doing to here.
    tmp::gtp { $title:
      name    => $title,
      version => gtp_instanceconfig[$title]['version'],
      ip      => gtp_instanceconfig[$title]['ip'],
      port    => gtp_instanceconfig[$title]['port'],
    }
  }

  gtp_instance { $gtp_instances: }
}
```

Comment: Can hiera works with defined types? I found there were no docs talking about hiera and defined types. Where can i find the detail docs? thx

Comment: @txworking It can't directly do defined types in the same way that it can do classes.  Instead of directly using defined types in your nodes, use classes - and you can have those classes realize any needed defined types based on that data in hiera.  For your example above, does that mean you need to have more than one `tmp::gtp` per node?

Comment: Yes. `tmp::gtp` is a defined type, and i need to have more than one `tmp::gtp` per node. What you mean is that i should define one class which contains many `tmp::gtp`?

Comment: @txworking Added notes to my answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Shane gave an excellent answer with a better way to approach your problem, but I want to address, "So I am thinking Puppet will not dynamically import a new pp file after the puppet master has been started."

That's kind of true.  When Puppet starts, it reads through all of its configuration files and then starts watching them for changes.  When the content of one of those files is updated, Puppet will reread the file.  Puppet also has a set of standard locations for files that it will consult when it needs to, so if you add a new class `foo::bar` to a node in a file it's monitoring, it'll look for a file named `foo/manifests/bar.pp` (or `foo/manifests/bar.rb`) in its `$modulepath`, even if it didn't need that file when it started up.

Importantly, `import` directives are only evaluated when the file they're in is parsed.  When the puppet master started, it read its `site.pp` file, saw the `import` statement, and found only `nodes/test1.pp`, so the only files it monitored for changes were `site.pp` and `nodes/test1.pp`.  It never saw `nodes/test2.pp`.

One workaround for this would be simply to `touch site.pp` after adding a new file to the `nodes` directory.  That will cause the puppet master to reread `site.pp`, which will cause it to reprocess the `import` statement and it will then see the new file.

In the long run, though, you're better off following Shane's recommendations and separating out your data from your code.  If you can structure your definitions to not need the `import` statement, you'll be better off; it does still have its uses, but in a lot of ways `import` is a relic of older Puppet practices that are no longer relevant.